# ScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a linearlayout and a viewpager, which contains a list view. I want the linearlayout(Restaurant page and the image) to go up when it is scrolled up. For that i tried to use scrollView but it does not work. What should I do?
[image: Screenshot]

This is the xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ResView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/header_restaurant_page" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Pre Order"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Pay Online"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:typeface="robotoRegular"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.csform.android.uiapptemplate.restaurant"
            android:background="#fff">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Include tag is for the header for restaurant details. 
And if possible, I want to stick the PagerSlidingTabStrip(Offer, menu, about, reviews) to top when it is scrolled.

Comment: may be try with height wrap content for scroll view

Comment: Add this line `<include layout="@layout/header_restaurant_page" />` before LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you can try that code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that easily with `CoordinatorLayout` and `TabLayout`

**(something like following example):**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- <include layout="@layout/header_restaurant_page" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pre Order"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pay Online"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarmain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:typeface="robotoRegular"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Remember, `ScrollView` can have only one child.
By the way.

Comment: For this, I would have to include  'com.android.support:design:23.1.0', which gives me issues like - Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined and Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: That is an another problem, try to add the latest SupportDesign

Comment: How should I do that, and is not 23.1.0 the latest?

Comment: Goto the Android Sdk manager and update it.i think the latest version was 23.1.1.and i highly suggest you to use that coordinatorlayout with my answer.this is the right path ;)

Comment: I tried that, it is not working. Same error, What should i do?

Comment: @HARSHILGOEL -  **Ask** a new question with the informations :)